# LIKE function for htmlspecialchars encoded row

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

i have summernote text editor and doing `htmlspecialchars($VALUE)` before insert to db, then `htmlspecialchars_decode($VALUE)` after getting to maintain text editor's changes...
But i also need to do search function for this row, so how to use LIKE function when row (VARCHAR) is encoded with htmlspecialchars()? is there any SQL function to strip those tags while selecting to perform LIKE function?

P.S
I'm using PDO and my query looks like:

```
$this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_tasks WHERE a_text LIKE '%$value%'");
```

and here, t_text looks like

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;i style=&quot;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);&quot;&gt;cdsfsadfasdf&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: SQL can deal with text, but not with HTML encoded text. It's better to store the unencoded text in the database and encode it when you need it.

Comment: @Andomar people are coming here not for the proper solution but for the quick fix. Even if it doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use binding param eg:

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM t_tasks WHERE a_text LIKE CONCAT('%', :value, '%'));
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
```

Comment: Surely you do realize this is not what has been asked

Comment: Well, fact is that, after that my problem got solved, its simple and short, so.... if you have better solution, could you provide?

Answer (score 1):

**Noisy Disclaimer: the following works as designed, and addresses the question being asked, but that does not make it a good idea or an example of best practice.**

Quite the contrary, I would suggest.  Sargability is completely defeated, and as you can see from reviewing the code, I have to go through some needless juggling and gyrations, because SQL is simply not the right tool for this job.

But, I wrote this when I needed it for an environment where I had no option but to work with data that was stored with encoded HTML entities -- and for legacy reasons could not be changed.

It's a MySQL stored function that converts entities to their utf8-encoded equivalent character.  For example:

```
mysql> SELECT decode_entities('I &hearts; doing &ldquo;clever&rdquo; things.') AS decoded_string;
+----------------------------------+
| decoded_string                   |
+----------------------------------+
| I ♥ doing “clever” things.       |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, for your query, if we wanted to test whether this...

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;i style=&quot;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);&quot;&gt;cdsfsadfasdf&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

...is `LIKE '<p><i style=%'`...

```
mysql> SELECT decode_entities('&lt;p&gt;&lt;i style=&quot;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);&quot;&gt;cdsfsadfasdf&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/p&gt;') LIKE '<p><i style=%' AS this_matches;
+--------------+
| this_matches |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

...we find that it is.

After defining the function, you'd use...

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT t.*, decoded_entities(t.a_text) AS a_text_decoded FROM t_tasks t WHERE decode_entities(t.a_text) LIKE CONCAT('%', :value, '%'));
```

---

Here's the function:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `decode_entities` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `decode_entities`(str LONGTEXT charset utf8) RETURNS longtext CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

-- decode HTML entities in database strings.

-- this processing is somewhat intensive due to the fact that this is clearly not something the database is
-- necessarily optimal place to accomlish; because of this, the function is optimized to quickly return strings that can't possibly contain entities

-- otherwise, we walk the string, looking for & ... ; then checking the matched inner contents for numeric (&#nnn;) and hex (&#xdddd;) literals,
-- failing that, we search for a named entity in the static string; if we end up with a decimal value, we utf-8 encode that value and replace
-- the entity, in place, in the string, with the utf-8 character; then advance our character pointer by one and then try again.

-- if we can't successfully decipher something that looks like an entity, we leave it as it was

-- the ordering of the values in the "entities' blob (entities are case sensitive) is something of a performance consideration; it may be desirable
-- that the most likely encountered entities in a given application be placed first in the blob, because there is a performance difference
-- of perhaps 30 usec (on a 1 GHz Opteron) when matching the first one compared to matching the last one 

-- copy/pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/49498332/1695906

  IF str IS NULL OR str NOT LIKE '%&%;%' THEN
    RETURN str;
  END IF;

  BEGIN
    DECLARE entities BLOB DEFAULT 'AElig,198,Aacute,193,Acirc,194,Agrave,192,Alpha,913,Aring,197,Atilde,195,Auml,196,Beta,914,Ccedil,199,Chi,935,Dagger,8225,Delta,916,ETH,208,Eacute,201,Ecirc,202,Egrave,200,Epsilon,917,Eta,919,Euml,203,Gamma,915,Iacute,205,Icirc,206,Igrave,204,Iota,921,Iuml,207,Kappa,922,Lambda,923,Mu,924,Ntilde,209,Nu,925,OElig,338,Oacute,211,Ocirc,212,Ograve,210,Omega,937,Omicron,927,Oslash,216,Otilde,213,Ouml,214,Phi,934,Pi,928,Prime,8243,Psi,936,Rho,929,Scaron,352,Sigma,931,THORN,222,Tau,932,Theta,920,Uacute,218,Ucirc,219,Ugrave,217,Upsilon,933,Uuml,220,Xi,926,Yacute,221,Yuml,376,Zeta,918,aacute,225,acirc,226,acute,180,aelig,230,agrave,224,alefsym,8501,alpha,945,amp,38,and,8743,ang,8736,apos,39,aring,229,asymp,8776,atilde,227,auml,228,bdquo,8222,beta,946,brvbar,166,bull,8226,cap,8745,ccedil,231,cedil,184,cent,162,chi,967,circ,710,clubs,9827,cong,8773,copy,169,crarr,8629,cup,8746,curren,164,dArr,8659,dagger,8224,darr,8595,deg,176,delta,948,diams,9830,divide,247,eacute,233,ecirc,234,egrave,232,empty,8709,emsp,8195,ensp,8194,epsilon,949,equiv,8801,eta,951,eth,240,euml,235,euro,8364,exist,8707,fnof,402,forall,8704,frac12,189,frac14,188,frac34,190,frasl,8260,gamma,947,ge,8805,gt,62,hArr,8660,harr,8596,hearts,9829,hellip,8230,iacute,237,icirc,238,iexcl,161,igrave,236,image,8465,infin,8734,int,8747,iota,953,iquest,191,isin,8712,iuml,239,kappa,954,lArr,8656,lambda,955,lang,9001,laquo,171,larr,8592,lceil,8968,ldquo,8220,le,8804,lfloor,8970,lowast,8727,loz,9674,lrm,8206,lsaquo,8249,lsquo,8216,lt,60,macr,175,mdash,8212,micro,181,middot,183,minus,8722,mu,956,nabla,8711,nbsp,160,ndash,8211,ne,8800,ni,8715,not,172,notin,8713,nsub,8836,ntilde,241,nu,957,oacute,243,ocirc,244,oelig,339,ograve,242,oline,8254,omega,969,omicron,959,oplus,8853,or,8744,ordf,170,ordm,186,oslash,248,otilde,245,otimes,8855,ouml,246,para,182,part,8706,permil,8240,perp,8869,phi,966,pi,960,piv,982,plusmn,177,pound,163,prime,8242,prod,8719,prop,8733,psi,968,quot,34,rArr,8658,radic,8730,rang,9002,raquo,187,rarr,8594,rceil,8969,rdquo,8221,real,8476,reg,174,rfloor,8971,rho,961,rlm,8207,rsaquo,8250,rsquo,8217,sbquo,8218,scaron,353,sdot,8901,sect,167,shy,173,sigma,963,sigmaf,962,sim,8764,spades,9824,sub,8834,sube,8838,sum,8721,sup1,185,sup2,178,sup3,179,sup,8835,supe,8839,szlig,223,tau,964,there4,8756,theta,952,thetasym,977,thinsp,8201,thorn,254,tilde,732,times,215,trade,8482,uArr,8657,uacute,250,uarr,8593,ucirc,251,ugrave,249,uml,168,upsih,978,upsilon,965,uuml,252,weierp,8472,xi,958,yacute,253,yen,165,yuml,255,zeta,950,zwj,8205,zwnj,8204';
    DECLARE len BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT LENGTH(str);
    DECLARE ptr BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE nxtamp BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE nxtsem BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE sbstr LONGTEXT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE decval SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE setpos SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE uenc TINYTEXT DEFAULT NULL;

    walk:
    LOOP
      SET ptr = ptr + 1;
      IF ptr >= len THEN
        LEAVE walk;
      END IF;

      SET nxtamp = LOCATE('&',str,ptr);
      IF NOT nxtamp THEN
        LEAVE walk;
      END IF;
      SET nxtsem = LOCATE(';',str,ptr + 1);
      IF NOT nxtsem THEN
        LEAVE walk;
      END IF;
      IF nxtsem < nxtamp THEN
        ITERATE walk;
      END IF;

      SET sbstr = SUBSTRING(str FROM nxtamp +1 FOR nxtsem - nxtamp - 1);

      IF sbstr RLIKE '^#[0-9]+$' THEN
        SET decval = TRIM(LEADING '#' FROM sbstr);
      ELSEIF sbstr RLIKE '^#x[0-9a-f]+$' THEN
        SET decval = CONV(TRIM(LEADING '#x' FROM sbstr),16,10);
      ELSE
        SET setpos = FIND_IN_SET(sbstr,entities);
        IF setpos > 0 THEN
          SET decval = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(entities,',',setpos + 1),',',-1);
        ELSE
          ITERATE walk;
        END IF;
      END IF;

      IF (decval > 0) THEN
        SET uenc = CHAR(CASE
            WHEN decval <= 0x7F THEN decval
            WHEN decval <= 0x7FF THEN 0xC080 | ((decval >> 6) << 8) | (decval & 0x3F)
            WHEN decval <= 0xFFFF THEN 0xE08080 | (((decval >> 12) & 0x0F ) << 16)  | (((decval >> 6) & 0x3F ) << 8) | (decval & 0x3F)
            ELSE NULL END);
        IF uenc IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(uenc) > 0 THEN
          SET str = INSERT(str, nxtamp, 1 + nxtsem - nxtamp, uenc);
        END IF;
      END IF;

    END LOOP;

    RETURN str;

  END;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

(n.b. these things are not called "tags" -- they are "HTML entities.")